12 Team 11 Event Schedule
Does anyone have a schedule with the following parameters?   12 teams, 11 events.   Each team can only play another team once and can only play each event once.

Is this not a classic round robin tournament? The circle method a the link is a very easy way to get a schedule.

Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! Puzzles for this site need to have some sort of interesting puzzly component; we don't just do math for you. A quick Google search turns up many apps designed for this purpose. (Comments copied from this deleted question)

I think this is actually a bit of a harder thing to figure out, because of the constraint Each team...can only play each event once.  So it's not a simple round-robin, because every team needs to play 11 games, that are all different events.  If Team 1 plays soccer against Team 2, then neither of those teams can play soccer against another team; they have to play badminton, or golf, or crokinole...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_coloring

@GentlePurpleRain: Interesting point.  Apparently Room Squares are what is needed for this and they do exist for 11 events, but are hard to construct.

@TylerSeacrest fandango96's answer below has a fairly simple algorithm for this, that can even be done by hand.  I independently came up with something similar with a bit of trial and error.  I don't know what Room Squares are, but it seems like they might be overkill for this problem?

@GentlePurpleRain:  fandango96's answer is just round robin tournament scheduling, where "events" are a synonym for "rounds" (see Jaap Scherphuis's link).  I agree this is pretty easy. I thought you were talking about adding a requirement that, for each round, you also have a soccer game, a badminton game, a golf game, etc., so you have events and rounds you have to keep track of. It's like double round robin tournament scheduling.  These make up the rows and columns of the Room Squares.

Here's a schedule based on this paper:
Round  1:  1v 7           11v 3                            6v 8   10v 4   12v 2            5v 9   
Round  2:  6v10    1v 8           12v 4                            7v 9   11v 5    2v 3           
Round  3:          7v11    1v 9            2v 5                            8v10   12v 6    3v 4   
Round  4:  4v 5            8v12    1v10            3v 6                            9v11    2v 7   
Round  5:  3v 8    5v 6            9v 2    1v11            4v 7                           10v12   
Round  6: 11v 2    4v 9    6v 7           10v 3    1v12            5v 8                           
Round  7:         12v 3    5v10    7v 8           11v 4    1v 2            6v 9                   
Round  8:                  2v 4    6v11    8v 9           12v 5    1v 3            7v10           
Round  9:                          3v 5    7v12    9v10            2v 6    1v 4            8v11   
Round 10:  9v12                            4v 6    8v 2   10v11            3v 7    1v 5           
Round 11:         10v 2                            5v 7    9v 3   11v12            4v 8    1v 6   

Note that each column corresponds to a different event.
I put schedules for $8, 10, ..., 48$ teams here.
Thanks to Tyler Seacrest for pointing out that this problem is called "Room Squares".


 It's possible to construct such a schedule using a simple algorithm.

The schedule is, with each triple representing the numbers of the 2 teams (0-indexed) and event number (0-indexed)

 (0, 1, 0)
 (0, 2, 1)
 (0, 3, 2)
 (0, 4, 3)
 (0, 5, 4)
 (0, 6, 5)
 (0, 7, 6)
 (0, 8, 7)
 (0, 9, 8)
 (0, 10, 9)
 (0, 11, 10)
 (1, 2, 2)
 (1, 3, 3)
 (1, 4, 4)
 (1, 5, 5)
 (1, 6, 6)
 (1, 7, 7)
 (1, 8, 8)
 (1, 9, 9)
 (1, 10, 10)
 (1, 11, 1)
 (2, 3, 4)
 (2, 4, 5)
 (2, 5, 6)
 (2, 6, 7)
 (2, 7, 8)
 (2, 8, 9)
 (2, 9, 10)
 (2, 10, 0)
 (2, 11, 3)
 (3, 4, 6)
 (3, 5, 7)
 (3, 6, 8)
 (3, 7, 9)
 (3, 8, 10)
 (3, 9, 0)
 (3, 10, 1)
 (3, 11, 5)
 (4, 5, 8)
 (4, 6, 9)
 (4, 7, 10)
 (4, 8, 0)
 (4, 9, 1)
 (4, 10, 2)
 (4, 11, 7)
 (5, 6, 10)
 (5, 7, 0)
 (5, 8, 1)
 (5, 9, 2)
 (5, 10, 3)
 (5, 11, 9)
 (6, 7, 1)
 (6, 8, 2)
 (6, 9, 3)
 (6, 10, 4)
 (6, 11, 0)
 (7, 8, 3)
 (7, 9, 4)
 (7, 10, 5)
 (7, 11, 2)
 (8, 9, 5)
 (8, 10, 6)
 (8, 11, 4)
 (9, 10, 7)
 (9, 11, 6)
 (10, 11, 8)

Steps to construct

 It's a simple greedy allocation of events to pairs of teams as all teams and events are equivalent (there's no inherent order).

 For each pair of teams (i,j) with j>i, we try to assign j-1 as the event and if that's not possible because either team has played that event before, we keep incrementing the event number (and rolling when we reach 11).

 The computational cost can be lowered by keeping track of previous allocations, but it's a pretty straightforward cache.

